# Is Angularjs used to create SPA website?

Tags: angularjs

I'm not familiar with it, can you clarify it? I don't want to create a SPA website.
Can I use Angularjs for non-spa website?

Comment: yes you can use it for non-spa too.

Comment: Yes please ignore people saying Angular = SPA  , if you want to use it was trying it out ,  for say a menu , something else -  you won't even need the routing if you have a way of handling routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS has been created for Single Page App (SPA) website. But this doesn't restricts one from creating non-SPA website or application. If one has incorporated routing in their application, then it makes a SPA application. I have worked on various applications with AngularJS as the scripting framework, some were SPA and some were non-SPA. It's actually to the developers or the application to decide to go with SPA or not.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS was cleverly built by some guys at Google and is open source.  It is absolutely not directly a SPA.  Over the years I have heard some people make wild statements like "Well, if you don't use Angular for its SPA features, then you might as well just use KnockoutJS!"

Nothing could be further from the truth on that as there are so many examples to pull from to defeat that argument!

You can use it without a database or file system and stub things out for testing, but you certainly want to consider your goals.

Build a Menu System with Angular - you can have a complete database driven menu system without any SPA.. so no routing with ng-route etc...

Plenty of people start out NOT doing a SPA as you just added an extra layer of complexity in understanding how Angular works.  So much power and things to build without the single page application.

Baby Steps!